# Xna Load Content. Cannot open file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna

I was trying to load a spritefont from Content.load.
But i get the error Cannot open File.

```
Font1 = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("/SpriteFont1");
```

Error

> Error loading "\SpriteFont1". Cannot open file.

i've searched the internet but i couldn't find anything.
I did corectly import a spritefont in my content file.

I hope some one can help me it would help me a lot.

![enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK2E2.png

Comment: Deleted my answer because this guy said the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5041806/3239917

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the xnb file for the spriteFont is correctly spelled (the xml code inside the file).

With this in mind, make sure that the SpriteFont1 file in your solution has been set as "Content" from the file properties.

Also, make sure that it is not inside a folder in the Content project (instead of on the root level).

Finally, make sure to set the root source of content correctly:

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
```

If you want my answer to be more detailed, please post the code with which you load the font, and also an image of the solution would be helpful.

Comment: Then, please post the extra stuff that I asked for or it will not be possible to give a correct answer :)

Comment: Just to scratch bullets, remove the "/" from "/font". Leave the code as: Font1 = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("font");

Comment: If i do that the file isnt found

Comment: Inside the font file, what do you have on the <FontName></FontName> tags?

Comment: It should not have the `/`. if the file isn't found, I would question if you really loaded it correctly into your project. Can you find the `font.xnb` in Projects>TCP-Client>TCP-Client>TCP-Client>Bin>X86>Debug>Content ?

Comment: I'm with Steve H, apart from checking the "Content" item, check when it gets copied (copied if newer, copy always, ...) on the file properties.
To see if it gets copied, its as easy as right clicking the game project, open containing folder and from there the bin\debug folders.

Comment: I dont have a xnb file how do i make it?

Comment: You don't. All the files inside the content project are transformed to xnb for XNA to process and use them.

Comment: There aren't any .xnb files in my project.

Comment: They are created automatically from all your content, but you don't use them as xnb. http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/sample/xnb_format